# Variable Problem in GameMaker Studio

Tags: game-maker

On obj_player I have a Create and Step event

Create:

```
/// Intialize Variables      
grav = 0.2;      
hsp = 0;     
vsp = 0;      
jumpspeed = 7;     
movepseed = 4;    
move = key_left + key_right
```

Step:

```
//Get the player's input       
key_right = keyboard_check(vk_right);      
key_left = -keyboard_check(vk_left);    
key_jump = keyboard_check_pressed(vk_space);     

//React to inputs      
move = key_left + key_right;      
hsp = move * movespeed;      
if (vsp < 10) vsp += grav;      

if (place_meeting(x,y+1,obj_wall))        
{         
    vsp = key_jump * -jumpspeed        
}        

//Horizontal Collision     
if (place_meeting(x+hsp,y,obj_wall))         
{       
    while(!place_meeting(x+sign(hsp),y,obj_wall))       
    {          
        x += sign(hsp);        
    }       
    hsp = 0;         
}               
x += hsp;       

//Vertical Collision     
if (place_meeting(x,y+vsp,obj_wall))     
{        
    while(!place_meeting(x,y+sign(vsp),obj_wall))    
    {    
        y += sign(vsp);    
    }    
    vsp = 0;     
}       
y += vsp;
```

Error Message:

```
FATAL ERROR in       
action number 1       
of Create Event        
for object obj_player:        

Variable obj_player.key_left(100007, -2147483648) not set before reading it.         
 at gml_Object_obj_player_CreateEvent_1 (line 7) - move = key_left + key_right
```

Whats wrong with this code? Ive been stuck on it for a couple days now, just really confused as I have seen this code work in action and for other people in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IysShLIaosk

Answer (score 1):

add

```
key_left = 0;
key_right = 0;
```

before

```
move = key_left + key_right;
```

in `Create:`

Both variables need to be initialized to some defined value before being read (`key_left + key_right` is a read of both) to set the move variable.

Comment: I added the move variable and key_left = 0; and key_right = 0; to my Create event.  I still receive " Variable obj_player.movespeed(100011, -2147483648) not set before reading it.
 at gml_Object_obj_player_StepNormalEvent_1 (line 8) - hsp = move * movespeed; "

Comment: That's a different error: You have a typo: You're initializing it as `movepseed`, not `movespeed`.